# Declaration: K&R

Tags: c, variables

I was reading Chapter 2 of The C programming language by K&R : "Types, Operators & Expressions", section 2.4, where in I found the below statements being made:

> If the variable in question is not automatic, the initialization is
>   done once only, conceptually before the program starts executing, and
>   the initializer must be a constant expression.An explicitly
>   initialized automatic variable is initialized each time the function
>   or block it is in is entered; the initializer may be any expression.

The above lines aren't too clear what do they mean?

Answer (score 11):

```
int a = 5;
int b = a; //error, a is not a constant expression

int main(void)
{
  static int c = a; //error, a is not a constant expression
  int d = a; //okay, a don't have to be a constant expression
  return 0;
}
```

only `d` is a automatic variable and so only `d` is allowed to get initialized with an other variable.

Answer (score 4):

An **automatic variable** is a normal variable.  These variables are created on the stack and get initialized every time through.  For instance:

```
int example_auto(){
    int foo = 0;
    foo++;
    return foo;
}
```

`foo` is initialized to `0` every time you call `example_auto()`.  The function always returns 1.

A **static variable** is a variable declared with `static`, or as a global variable (outside of any function).  Unlike automatic variables, these variables are initialized once, at (or close to) program startup.  For instance:

```
int example_static(){
    static int foo = 0;
    foo++;
    return foo;
}
```

`foo` is initialized once.  `example_static()` returns 1 the first time you call it, then 2, then 3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

*An explicitly initialized automatic variable is initialized each time the function or block it is in is entered*:

In addition to the other answers, *Automatic*, as the name implies, also has to do with the way the variable is treated during run-time.  i.e. that its life, within the logical block it is defined, will be created, and destroyed automatically upon entering and leaving.  ***[Memory is allocated and deallocated automatically within the variable's context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)***.  There is no need to explicitly create or destroy memory, as this is done each time the logical block (defined by `{...}`) is entered and exited.  Thus the term *automatic*.

*the initializer may be any expression.*

An *automatic* variable may be initialized using other, previously initialized variables, constants, or expressions.

```
#define MAX 20.0

float d;

int func(void)
{
    int a = 10;  //automatic
    int b = a + 3; //automatic
    float c = MAX; //automatic 
    d = MAX;  //d is a file global, not automatic, 
              //memory created outside of local scope, 
              //memory is not de-allocated when function exits
    static int e = 0; //Not automatic as static gives local variables life 
                      //beyond the function, i.e. outside scope of {...}
                      //memory, and value of e remain when function exits
                      //and between calls

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a C-block you can define two kind of local variables : static and auto. Be aware that local only means that the variable is visible inside the function only.

An auto variable is then re-created each time you call the function/block, and destroyed when the control gets out the function/block. It is then initialized each time it is created.

A static local variable is created only once in whole life of the program. It is destroyed and the end of the program. And it is initialized at the same time it is created : only once at the beginning of the program (conceptually, it may be slightly different).

Answer (score 0):

This states that a local variable also known as an automatic variable can be initialized by a constant or non constant expression -

```
int a = 5;

int main()
{
    int c = a; // local or automatic variable initialized by a non 
    constant variable
}
```

But an external also known as a global variable and static variables cannot be initialized by non constant variables.

```
int a = 3
int b = a // cannot be initialized by non constant variable

int main()
{
static int d;
d = a // cannot be initialized by a non constant variable
}
```

It also states that the an automatic or local variable are re-intialized each time the block of code they are in is ran by the compiler. Because the memory location of the variable is automatically allocated and deallocated by the compiler every time it enters the code block.

```
void abc(void);// function parameter

int main()
{
   abc();
   abc();
}
void abc()
{
  int i = 0;// automatic variable i is re-intialized every time abc is called
  static x = 0; //static variable retains its value
  i ++ ;
  x ++;
  printf("%d\n",i );
  printf("%d\n",x );
}
```

Output - 1 1 1 2